# Parcelable change the orginal data

Tags: java, android

I am implementing `RecycleView` that will display list of skills those skills passed form another fragment using `Parcelable` the issue that when I delete item from the skills that display on `RecycleView` and back to the previous fragment the item also deleted from the orginal arraylist

Here is the `Parcelable` object

```
public class Skills implements Parcelable {
private ArrayList<String> skills;

public ArrayList<String> getVacancySkills() {
    return skills;
}

public void setSkills(ArrayList<String> skills) {
    this.skills = skills;
}


@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeStringList(this.skills);
}

public Skills() {
}

protected Skills(Parcel in) {
    this.skills = in.createStringArrayList();
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<Skills> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Skills>() {
    @Override
    public Skills createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
        return new Skills(source);
    }

    @Override
    public Skills[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Skills[size];
    }
};
}
```

and here is the  passing data

```
      @OnClick(R.id.card_add_skill)
public void showAddSkills() {
    Bundle data = new Bundle();

    Skills skills = new Skills();
    skills.setSkills(skillsLit);
    data.putParcelable(ExtraKeys.VACANCY_SKILLS, skills);

    VacancyEditSkillsFragment vacancyEditSkillsFragment = new VacancyEditSkillsFragment();

    FragmentUtils.addFragment(
            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(),
            vacancyEditSkillsFragment
            ,
            true,
            App.getContext().getString(R.string.skills), data

    );

}
```

and here is the fragment that recive the Parcable arraylist of strings

```
  public class VacancyEditSkillsFragment extends Fragment {


@BindView(R.id.rc_edit_skill_recycle)
RecyclerView editSkillsRecycle;

private Skills mSkills;

private EditVacancySkillsAdapter mEditVacancySkillsAdapter;

public VacancyEditSkillsFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mSkills = getArguments().getParcelable(ExtraKeys.VACANCY_SKILLS);
    }

    mEditVacancySkillsAdapter = new EditVacancySkillsAdapter(mSkills.getVacancySkills());
    editSkillsRecycle.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    editSkillsRecycle.setAdapter(mEditVacancySkillsAdapter);


}

public static VacancyEditSkillsFragment newInstance() {
    VacancyEditSkillsFragment fragment = new VacancyEditSkillsFragment();
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_vacancy_edit_skills, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    return view;
}

  }
```

and here is the adapter code

```
     public class EditVacancySkillsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<EditVacancySkillsAdapter.EditSkillViewHolder> {

private List<String> skills;


public class EditSkillViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    @BindView(R.id.tv_skill_name)
    TextView skillTitle;
    @BindView(R.id.iv_reomve_skill)
    ImageView deleteSkill;


    public EditSkillViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        deleteSkill.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(view.getId()== R.id.iv_reomve_skill)
        {
            skills.remove(getAdapterPosition());
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}

public EditVacancySkillsAdapter(ArrayList<String> sections) {
    this.skills = sections;
    if (skills == null) {
        skills = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}

@Override
public EditSkillViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.item_edit_vacancy_skill, parent, false);

    return new EditSkillViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(EditSkillViewHolder holder, int position) {


    holder.skillTitle.setText(skills.get(position));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return skills.size();
}


   }
```

Comment: what we don't expects **More code less explanation**, what we expect **Less code more explanation**

Comment: let me explain , i have two fragments and i used parcable to pass data from the first one to the second as arraylist of strings the issue was when i remove item from recived array list in the scond fragment and go back to the first fragment the reomved item from the scond fragment also reomved from the first one .

Answer (score 0):

This is as expected.

What is parcellable in simple term is:- It allows you to send a Object across different components. You are referencing the same object in both the components. Parcellable has implemented on top the object. So if any change happens to the object anywhere in the component will reflect back to rest of the component which uses the same object.

I hope you understood.

What you should do is send a copy of the object instead of the original object.

How to clone a parcellable object is by this:-

```
Foo foo1 = new Foo("a", "b", "c");
Parcel p = Parcel.obtain();
p.writeValue(foo1);
p.setDataPosition(0);
Foo foo2 = (Foo)p.readValue(Foo.class.getClassLoader());
p.recycle();
```

I hope this will help!